# Yacc header not available for Flex using Autotools

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, autotools

I am trying to write a simple calculator compiler. This simple example was taken from pages 13 and 14 of [Lex and Yacc Tutorial](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/download/LexAndYaccTutorial.pdf) written by Tom Niemann.

I want to add [GNU Autotools](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/autoconf.html) for this compiler.

Here I show you file contents:

- `pgfs_cmplr.l`:

  ```
  %{
  #include <stdlib.h>
  void yyerror(char*);
  // #include "pgfs_cmplr.h"
  %}

  %%

  [0-9]+  { yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
  [-+\n]+ return *yytext;
  [ \t]   ;
  .       yyerror("invalid character");
  <<EOF>> { yyterminate(); }

  %%

  int yywrap(void) {
    return 1;
  }
  ```
- `pgfs_cmplr.y`:

  ```
  %{
  #include <stdio.h>
  int yylex(void);
  void yyerror(char*);
  %}

  %token INTEGER

  %%

  program:
         program expr '\n'  { printf("%d\n", $2); }
         |
         ;

  expr:
         INTEGER            { $$ = $1; }
         | expr '+' expr    { $$ = $1 + $3; }
         | expr '-' expr    { $$ = $1 - $3; }
         ;

  %%

  int yyerror(char* s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: \'%s\' not valid.\n", s);
    return 0;
  }

  int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
  }
  ```
- `Configure.am`, many lines are in `...`:

  ```
  AC_PREREQ([2.69])
  ...
  AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall foreign dist-bzip2])
  AC_LANG_C
  AC_PROG_CC_C99
  AC_PROG_YACC
  AC_PROG_LEX
  m4_ifdef([AM_PROG_AR], [AM_PROG_AR])
  ...
  AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
  AC_OUTPUT
  ```
- `Makefile.am`, many lines are in `...`:

  ```
  ...
  ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
  AM_YFLAGS = -t -d -v
  bin_PROGRAMS = pgfs_cmplr
  pgfs_cmplr_SOURCES = src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.y src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.c
  ```

So when I execute `make` (as they were above) it throws:

```
$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
depbase=`echo src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.c &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l:9:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'yylval'
{ yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
  ^
src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l:9:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'INTEGER'
{ yylval = atoi(yytext); return INTEGER; }
                                ^
2 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This could be expected because Flex does not know where tokens are defined, so I uncomment `//#include "pgfs_cmplr.h"` at line 4 of `pgfs_cmplr.l`, and finally I execute again `make`, and it throws this:

```
$ make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
/bin/sh ./ylwrap src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l lex.yy.c src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.c -- flex  
depbase=`echo src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.o$||'`;\
    gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -MT src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.c &&\
    mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Po
src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l:4:10: fatal error: 'pgfs_cmplr.h' file not found
#include "pgfs_cmplr.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[1]: *** [src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.o] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What should I do to solve this issue?

I have tried including `"pgfs_cpmplr.tab.h"`, `"pgfs_cpmplr.h"`, `"y.tab.h"`, but anyone works. :(

Comment: It would certainly help to see what autotools' Makefile actually did before that error was generated. What yacc/bison and lex/flex commands did it execute, exactly? Did it run bison/yacc before attempting to compile the lexer? (And why don't you just look at ls and see what the header file is called? If you just `yacc -y -d` it will be called `y.tab.h` but most of us would prefer to invoke something like `bison -d -o pgfs_cmplr.tab.c` which will put the header file in `pgfs_cmplr.tab.h`. In a Makefile, even better would be to use the `--defines` flag to explicitly specify a header file name.

Comment: @rici By points…
1) I ain't sure which bison/yacc (just "bison") and flex/lex (just "flex") commands were executed
How should I be sure?, I have disabled `SILENT_RULES`, by commenting `#AM_SILENT_RULES([yes])` in `configure.ac`.

Comment: @rici 2) I ain't sure if bison was executed before flex. That is why I was asking for a _correct_ line in `Makefile.am` to do this. I know that bison must be executed before flex, to define tokens (specified in bison source file) and many things like these that will be used or called in flex source code.

Comment: @rici 3) In order to generate `pgfs_complr.tab.c`, How should I set this in `Makefile.am`?

Comment: I have no idea how to convince autotools to join the 21st century. I suppose it still has its place but it's too arcane for me. Sorry. It doesn't matter which order bison and flex are called, but it does matter that bison be invoked before the flex-generated program is compiled.  I would think that autotools would get that right but it would be nice to see what commands are actually being run (in a clean build, of course).

Answer (score 0):

One of the things the Autotools try to do is to wrap various local tools to provide behavior that is consistent across platforms and tool sets.  In this vein, when Autoconf's `AC_PROG_YACC` selects GNU Bison as the `yacc` binary, it automatically provides the `-y` flag for improved consistency with traditional `yacc`.  Bison's manual [explains](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Bison-Options.html#Bison-Options) that this

> Most importantly, imitate[s] Yacc’s output file name conventions, so that
>   the parser implementation file is called y.tab.c, and the other
>   outputs are called y.output and y.tab.h.

Thus, when you designate a `*.y` among a target's sources and `-d` among the relevant `YFLAGS`, you should expect that the generated definitions will be in a file named `y.tab.h`, even when you're using Bison rather than a true YACC.  Thus `y.tab.h` is the file that you should `#include`.  You may also want to name it among your `BUILT_SOURCES`.

If you wish, you can work around this behavior by writing your own rules into your `Makefile.am` for generating the parser's C source and header, and naming only those, as opposed to the original `.y` file, among your target's sources.  In that case, you would also want to name both generated files among your `BUILT_SOURCES`, and to name the `.y` file among your `EXTRA_SOURCES`, lest it be omitted from generated distribution packages.

Note, too, that even when you do not use `-y` with `bison`, it (by default) puts the generated symbol tables corresponding `foo.y` into a header named `foo.tab.h`, not `foo.h` as you seem to have expected.

Comment: Any `y.tab.h` or `pgfs_cmplr.tab.h` or  `pgfs_cmplr.h` is generated with commands in `Makefile.am` as they are shown above.

Comment: @Israel, do you mean ***not*** any of those headers is generated?  Neither in `src/lab` or in the project root?  That would suggets an ordering problem (flex runs before bison).  Have you tried adding `src/lab/y.tab.h` to your `BUILT_SOURCES` variable, as I suggested?  That will cause Automake to produce a Makefile that, among other things, tries to build `y.tab.h` very early.

Comment: It might also be worth your while to look at the generated `Makefile.in` to confirm what targets are built from `pgfs_cmplr.y`.

Comment: Yes, I mean that with `pgfs_cmplr_SOURCES = src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.y src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l` in `Makefile.am` any of those files (`y.tab.h`, `pgfs_cmplr.tab.h` or `pgfs_cmplr.h`) are generated in `.` (root), `src` or `src/lab` directory, after I run `make`.

Comment: Before add any line about `BUILT_SOURCES`, grep (`grep -i "tab.h" Makefile.in`) any `tab.h` pattern in `Makefile.in` and it throws only one line: `$(AM_V_YACC)$(am__skipyacc) $(SHELL) $(YLWRAP) $< y.tab.c $@ y.tab.h `echo $@ | $(am__yacc_c2h)` y.output $*.output -- $(YACCCOMPILE)`.

Comment: After add `BUILT_SOURCES = src/lab/y.tab.h` and keep `pgfs_cmplr_SOURCES = src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.y src/lab/pgfs_cmplr.l`, I `make` it again and it throws `make: *** No rule to make target 'src/lab/y.tab.h', needed by 'all'.  Stop.` and I `grep` it in `Makefile.in` and it threw almost the same: `BUILT_SOURCES = src/lab/y.tab.h` and `$(AM_V_YACC)$(am__skipyacc) $(SHELL) $(YLWRAP) $< y.tab.c $@ y.tab.h \`echo $@ | $(am__yacc_c2h)\` y.output $*.output -- $(YACCCOMPILE)`

Comment: Finally I tried to bison/flex/compile sources files without autotools in a clean sandbox directory. Source files are: `pgfs_cmplr.l` and `pgfs_cmplr.y`.
First I execute `bison -d -y -v pgfs_cmplr.y` and it generates `y.output`, `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`. Then, I execute `flex pgfs_cmplr.l ` and it generates `lex.yy.c`, and finally I `gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o pgfs_cmplr` and it generates `pgfs_cmplr` file.
So, source code at least compiles out of autotools.